# Service Worker not working in Angular after page reload

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I've implemented a Service Worker in my Angular application to cache APIs for offline use. Everything works perfectly on my local machine. However, when I deploy my app on the server, I encounter a problem.

The Service Worker initially functions as expected, but when I reload the app or open it in a new tab, it is not working anymore. I've noticed a manual workaround: if I stop and start the Service Worker from Chrome Dev Tools (Application > Service Worker), it begins working again. You can see a screenshot of the Dev Tools in this screenshot.
[SS of Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rJu4.png)

I'm relatively new to working with Service Workers, and I was unable to figure out how to restart my Service Worker. I came across a solution that suggests registering the Service Worker again via this link: (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13351). However, even after trying this approach, my issue persists.